# How to get filename in log4cplus in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, log4cplus

I want to get current file name, but I don't know how to get it.

For example:
In config.properties file:

```
log4cplus.rootLogger=TRACE, OTS_H, OTS_D

log4cplus.appender.OTS_H=log4cplus::TimeBasedRollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.MaxHistory=10
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.FilenamePattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}_OTS.csv
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout  
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.filters.1=log4cplus::spi::StringMatchFilter
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.filters.1.StringToMatch=OK
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.filters.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.filters.2=log4cplus::spi::DenyAllFilter
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.RollOnClose=false
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.Schedule=DAILY
log4cplus.appender.OTS_H.CreateDirs=true

log4cplus.appender.OTS_D=log4cplus::TimeBasedRollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.MaxHistory=10
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.FilenamePattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_OTS.csv
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout  
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.filters.1=log4cplus::spi::LogLevelRangeFilter
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.filters.1.LogLevelMin=ERROR
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.filters.1.LogLevelMax=ERROR
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.filters.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.filters.2=log4cplus::spi::DenyAllFilter
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.RollOnClose=false
log4cplus.appender.OTS_D.Schedule=HOURLY
```

And in my main.cpp

```
ConfigureAndWatchThread configureThread("config.properties", 10000);
Logger logger = Logger::getRoot();

int main(){

    // do something...
}
```

If use a function get now date from log4cplus and "2016-04-13-12-30_OTS.csv" and "2016-04-13_OTS.csv" filename, how to write the function/coding?

Could you help me to it, please?

Answer (score 0):

<s>log4cplus has [`FileAppnder::getName()`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1Appender.html#a1830bdf9afaffd6045596d709abb9df8) function. To get to the appender, use [`Logger::getAppender()`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1Logger.html#a7fd4a9b9f904cefad2d973c83a514035).</s>

However, why do you need to do this at all?

**UPDATE**

I was wrong. `getName()` does not get you the file name.

I guess the only alternative for you is to derive your own appender from `FileAppender` and add the necessary function, or patch your sources of log4cplus to add such function.

Comment: However, why do you need to do this at all?  -> Because I want to know which one *.csv is editing.

Comment: cout<<logger.getName()<<endl; // get "root" , isn't *.csv file. And I don't know how to use 'Logger::getAppender()'.

Comment: Hi wilx, it only get "OTS_H" &"OTS_D" by FileAppnder::getName() function. But, I want to get "2016-04-13-12-30_OTS.csv". Could you any suggestion, please?

Comment: Thanks for your help. And.... if I use 'TimeBasedRollingFileAppender',  which function could known what 'FilenamePattern' format setting from config.properties file?